# How to get rid of ThinkPad "TrackPoint Scrolling Tips" dialog

Tags: thinkpad, trackpoint

**UPDATE 2: NOT SOLVED AFTER ALL**

> Unfortunately this setting gets **reset** after ***EVERY SINGLE REBOOT***.

Question:

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad (T400) that has been configured to use the middle button above the touchpad as a middle-click button. (works just fine)

However when you click 3 or more times in a short time span (~3 seconds) it pops up a dialog:

> ### TrackPoint Scrolling Tips    [X]
>
> Would you like to learn how to use center button for the TrackPoint scrolling feature?
>
> [Yes]  [No]
>
> [_] Don't show this reminder again
>
> This reminder can be re-enabled on the TrackPoint Properties page in the ControlPanel
>
> [image]

I would be quite happy if I could click the checkbox and then the No button but that doesn't make the dialog go away forever... nor does clicking the checkbox and the Yes button, or checkbox and the [X]... or any other combo.

Does anyone know where the registry setting for this is so that I can force it to never ever show up again?

**Original UPDATE: Thought to be solved**

The dialog that pops up is useless at changing the settings but going deep, deep, deep into the control panel shows a dialog that lets you turn off the "tips".

Start > Control Panel > Mouse > UltraNav > TrackPoint > Settings > [_] Enable TrackPoint Scrolling Tips > OK

Comment: Have you tried updating your trackpoint drivers?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't work for me :(  The box was already unchecked.  I get this darn pop-up at least every hour when I'm cruising the web in Firefox.  The center button works fine -but if I'm scrolling down a long webpage that darn pop-up always pops up sooner or later.

VERY annoying.  I'll keep searching for a better fix.

Comment: Agreed! It seems the internal logic somewhere is flawed and keeps resetting itself - I wonder if any Thinkpad engineers follow SuperUser? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try uninstalling the Thinkvantage UltraNav Utility.  The Trackpoint and UltraNav will still work without it as the driver is separate.